# Summation in SQL over a computed column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Trans-SQL related question, concerning summations over a computed column.

I am having a problem with double-counting of these computed values.

Usually I would extract all the raw data and post-process it in Perl, but I can't do that on this occasion due to the particular reporting system we need to use.  I'm relatively inexperienced with the intricacies of SQL, so I thought I'd refer this to the experts.

My data is arranged in the following tables (highly simplified and reduced for the purposes of clarity):

`Patient` table:

- PatientId
- PatientSer

`Course` table

- PatientSer
- CourseSer
- CourseId

`Diagnosis` table

- PatientSer
- DiagnosisId

`Plan` table

- PlanSer
- CourseSer
- PlanId

`Field` table

- PlanSer
- FieldId
- FractionNumber
- FieldDateTime

What I would like to do is find the difference between the maximum fraction number and the minimum fraction number over a range of dates in the FieldDateTime in the FieldTable.  I would like to then sum these values over the possible plan ids associated with a course, but I do not want to double count over the two particular diagnosis ids (A or B or both) that I may encounter for a patient.

So, for a patient with two diagnosis codes (A and B) and two plans in the same course of treatment (Plan1 and Plan2), with a difference in fraction numbers of 24 for the first plan and 5 for the second what I would like to get out is something like this:

```
 - **PatientId  CourseId PlanId DiagnosisId  FractionNumberDiff  Sum
 - AB1234       1        Plan1  A            24                  29
 - AB1234       1        Plan1  B            *                   *
 - AB1234       1        Plan2  A            5                   * 
 - AB1234       1        Plan2  B            *                   *
```

I've racked my brains about how to do this, and I've tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    Patient.PatientId,
    Course.CourseId,
    Plan.PlanId,
    MAX(fractionnumber OVER PARTITION(Plan.PlanSer)) - MIN(fractionnumber OVER PARTITION(Plan.PlanSer)) AS FractionNumberDiff,
    SUM(FractionNumberDiff OVER PARTITION(Course.CourseSer)
FROM
    Patient P
INNER JOIN
    Course C ON (P.PatientSer = C.PatientSer)
INNER JOIN
    Plan Pl ON (Pl.CourseSer = C.CourseSer)
INNER JOIN
    Diagnosis D ON (D.PatientSer = P.PatientSer)
INNER JOIN
    Field F ON (F.PlanSer = Pl.PlanSer)
WHERE
    FieldDateTime > [Start Date]
    AND FieldDateTime < [End Date]
```

But this just double-counts over the diagnosis codes, meaning that I end up with 58 instead of 29.

Any ideas about what I can do?

Comment: Your problem (in all likelihood) has nothing to do with a computed column and everything to do with joins producing more intermediate results than you are accounting for.

Comment: Come on the query is not valid syntax.  No kidding it will duplicate Diagnosis if there are duplicate.  Why are you even joining to a table you are not using?

Comment: If, for whatever reason, you want to join to the table Diagnosis (e.g. to find only patients with a record in the diagnosis table), instead of join directly to the table, try joining `(SELECT PatientSer FROM Diagnosis GROUP BY PatientSer) D`

Answer (score 0):

change the FractionNumberDiff to

```
MAX(fractionnumber) OVER (PARTITION BY Plan.PlanSer) -
MIN(fractionnumber) OVER (PARTITION BY Plan.PlanSer) AS FractionNumberDiff
```

and remove the "SUM(FractionNumberDiff OVER PARTITION(Course.CourseSer)"

make the exisitng query as a derived table and calcualte the SUM(FractionNumberDiff) there

```
SELECT *, SUM(FractionNumberDiff) OVER ( PARTITION BYCourse.CourseSer)
FROM
(
   < the modified existing query here>
) AS d
```

as for the double counting issue, please post some sample data and the expected result